# How can I write a piece of text over my rectangles in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a few long rectangles I create using the following code:

How do I write text above every rectangle? I have tried append "text" to the enter selection and also tried appending "text" on "ttest" after all my code but it doesn't work out for me.

Any help is greatly appretiated!
    var ttest = SVGTTest
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(ttestArray);

```
ttest.exit()
    .style("opacity", TTEST_OPACITY)
    .transition()
    .duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*300)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove();

ttest.enter()
    .append("rect");

ttest
    .attr("x", function(d, i){
        var startIndex = (ttestArray[i][0]+1)*100;
        return xScale(startIndex);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i){
        return yScale(ttestArray[i][3]);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d, i){
        var endIndex = (ttestArray[i][1]-ttestArray[i][0])*100;
        return xScale(endIndex);
    })
    .attr("height", 3)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .transition().duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*500)
    .style("opacity", TTEST_OPACITY)
    .style("fill", "#000000");
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to append both elements (the svg `rect` and `text` elements) separately.  A common way of handling this is to bind an enter selection that creates svg `g` group elements, then use that selection to append the `rect` and `text` elements individually:

```
var rects = d3.selectAll("g.rectGroup")
    .data(data);

var rectEnter = rects.enter().append("g") 
    .attr("class", "rectGroup");

rectEnter.append("rect").attr({..});
rectEnter.append("text").attr({..});

rects.exit().remove();
```

Comment: Using this approach, but largely with the original poster's own code (I've had to modify bits and guess other bits to get it to work), here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/hfsaopqd/3/

Comment: Thank you for this. I have a single problem with this solution you have provided. I am dynamically adding more "rectangles" with a click of a button. The information for coordinates and text are added to the array "ttestArray" and the code for D3 is run again. With your code the following happens. When the first element is added to "ttestArray", D3 draws it, then when a 2nd element is added to "ttestArray", D3's enter selection draw BOTH again, this means the first on is there twice now. I can see it because the line and text become darker when two of the overlap. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly write a text into a rect element. I would recommend you create a group element and add the rectangle and a text element inside. Then you could also use mouse events directy on that group (if you want) like you can see in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fbwdajwm/1/

So basically you add the goup element like this:

```
var svgg = svg.selectAll("g.myGroup")
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append("g");
```

Then you cann access your data again like this:

```
svgg.each(function (d, i) {

    selection = d3.select(this);
    selection.append("rect")
    // ...
});
```

Edit:

Ok, I read the comment you gave to Henry and decided to update the fiddle so it fits the description you gave to him. See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fbwdajwm/4/

So what did I do? Whenever the button is clicked I update the data then I call a function that updates the Rectangles (including their texts). Now it is important that you really select the groups that you have created before when applying new data. I do this via a class and the Selector `'g.myGroup'`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if I do it this way the text would have to be positioned inside of the rectangle, right? I want it to be above it most importantly. How would I do this?

Comment: No, the text can be whereever you want it to be. You add the text node separately and give values for dx and dy yourself. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fbwdajwm/2/